# Show that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, either $7 \mid n^3 - 1$, $7 \mid n^3$, or $7 \mid n^3 + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I want to show, that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$
7 \,\mid\, n^3 - 1 \,\text{or}\, 7 \,\mid\, n^3 \,\text{or}\, 7 \,\mid\, n^3 + 1
$$

I can't find a way to proof this.

Comment: How is it "clear" in your intuition? If you can't prove it, it's not clear.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You are right. It's now clear in my intuition. I removed it from the question.

Comment: Hint: Fermat's little theorem and note: $ n^7-n = n(n^6-1) =n(n^3-1)(n^3+1) $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider all the possible values of $n^3 \mod 7$

\begin{align}
0^3 &\equiv 0 \mod7\\
1^3 &\equiv 1\mod7\\
2^3 &\equiv 1 \mod7\\
3^3 &\equiv-1\mod7\\
4^3 &\equiv1 \mod7\\
5^3 &\equiv -1 \mod7\\
6^3 &\equiv -1 \mod7
\end{align}

Note that these can be easily found for $4, 5, 6$ because $-a \equiv 7-a \mod7$

Answer (score 1):

John Lou's approach is the fastest. Here's another.

If $7|n$ then we are done, because in that case $7|n^3$.

So suppose otherwise. Then $n=7k\pm i$ where $i=1, 2, 3$, for some integer $k$.

We have

$$(7k\pm i)^3=343k^3\pm 147ik^2\mp 21i^2k\pm i^3$$

The first three terms are divisible by $7$. But for $i=1, 2, 3$, $\pm i^3$ is either one more or one less than a multiple of $7$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Because by the Fermat little theorem  $n^7-n$ is divisible by $7$ and
$$n^7-n=n(n^6-1)=n(n^3-1)(n^3+1).$$